# IE sending POST instead of GET with $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have little problem. I can't use `AcceptVerb.Get` on some ASP.NET MVC actions because when I use `$.get(..)` IE sends POST instead of GET. Why???

edit:
Forget to add that Firefox work as I want - the same code in Firefox performs GET.

Comment: Could you provide some code samples?

Comment: Code is simply $.get(url, addata, function(data){ ... });

Comment: http://dario-g.com/jQuery-Ajax-i-IE-0-108.aspx - this is my solution for this (in Polish but everyone can understand the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that $.get() works the same way as $.load() where if you send extra parameters it will perform a post.